# How to Include a flash object into a xhtml page

Tags: flash, xhtml

I am trying to create a project in which I want to include a falsh object.I have the .swf file named as movie.swf.
Now in my xhtml page I write this code

```
<div id="movie">
  here i want flash content
</div>
```

where the flash content should be written,
and my script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var so = new SWFObject("movie.swf", "movie", "400", "200", "8", "#336699");
   so.write("movie");
</script>
```

but this is not working.
Please find the error for the code or is there anything else I have to write.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the following in your `<head></head>`?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
```

You'll need to allow for your SWFObject to have access to swfobject.js file either via that [Google AJAX Libraries API](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/hosted_library) or locally. Here's further documentation:

[How to embed Flash Player content using SWFObject dynamic publishing](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation)